# Missing dependency xcb-glx when trying to install Picom

Tags: linux, terminal, dependencies

Tried running
`meson --buildtype=release . build`
`

```
Run-time dependency libev found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Library ev found: YES
Library m found: YES
Run-time dependency x11 found: YES 1.7.5
Run-time dependency x11-xcb found: YES 1.7.5
Run-time dependency xcb-renderutil found: YES 0.3.9
Run-time dependency xcb-image found: YES 0.4.0
Run-time dependency xext found: YES 1.3.4
Run-time dependency pixman-1 found: YES 0.40.0
Run-time dependency xcb-render found: YES 1.14
Run-time dependency xcb-damage found: YES 1.14
Run-time dependency xcb-randr found: YES 1.14
Run-time dependency xcb-sync found: YES 1.14
Run-time dependency xcb-composite found: YES 1.14
Run-time dependency xcb-shape found: YES 1.14
Run-time dependency xcb-xinerama found: YES 1.14
Run-time dependency xcb-xfixes found: YES 1.14
Run-time dependency xcb-present found: YES 1.14
Run-time dependency xcb-glx found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

src/meson.build:31:1: ERROR: Dependency "xcb-glx" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

I looked up a solution on here and Github and none of them have worked.

Tried installing `libwayland-dev`

then tried installing `libxcb-glx0-dev

```
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sudo apt install libxcb-render-util0-dev`